# How do I make JavaScript generate a new link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched so much for this. How do I make JS make a link that goes something along the lines of `example.com/index.php#number`?

Example of what i mean - https://gyazo.com/428ea0c819d340a699a328baaf4c1c1f

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an anchor element and add it to the page?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Would you like to link to anywhere in the same page or are you asking to create anchored links?

Comment: Basically, I saw a video that was 'showing' how to make a video chat site and it would generate a link with random numbers and letters. It looked like this: https://gyazo.com/428ea0c819d340a699a328baaf4c1c1f
edit: the 'showing' means it was just telling you how to copy and paste code

Comment: Okay now I get what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that you have your base address, "http://www.example.com/index.php", what you want to do is to add a new part to the url

```
const base = "http://www.example.com/index.php"
let number  = 42
location.href = base + "#" + number
```

which will redirect you to "http://www.example.com/index.php#42"

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what are you trying to achieve here but I hope this helps.

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
let url_link_title = document.createTextNode("Your Title Here.");
a.appendChild(url_link_title);
a.title = "Your Title Here";
a.href = "http://yoursampleaddress.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: see the comments under the post